# Nginx rewrite anything after specific keyword

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, rule

I want to rewrite all requests after "`whois`" keyword in `url` to `whois.php` in `nginx` but can't find suitable rules.

e.g. rewrite `domain.com/whois.php/TEST.COM` to `whois.php?domain=TEST.COM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of options available to you. One solution is:

```
location ~* ^/whois.php/ {
    rewrite ^(/whois.php)/(.*)$ $1?domain=$2 last;
}
```

Place the location block above other regex locations that might match, as regex locations are executed on the basis of the first one that matches.

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.